# Cannot assign argument type string[] to parameter of type {name:string}

Tags: angular

Hey Guys a have a little problem i have a user class that has the roles property which of type Array<{name:string}>

```
    export class User {
           id!: number; 
           firstName!: string; 
           lastName!: string; 
           emailId!: string; 
           roles!: Array<{name:string}>; 
    }

  selRoles!: Array<{name:string}>;
```

Than i try to push some name:string values to the roles array of the user object but it don't work.
How can convert the type of data.roles.map(role => {return {name: role.name}});
and push it to the array?

```
this.userService.getUserById(this.id).subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data; 
      this.user.roles.push( data.roles.map(role => {return {name: role.name}}).map(role => role.name);
      this.selRoles = data.roles.map(role => {return {name: role.name}});
```

Exception=>

```
 Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; }'.
Property 'name' is missing in type 'string[]' but required in type '{ name: string;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is twofold.
First, you're mapping your data to array of strings in this part of your code:

```
.map(role => role.name)
```

You will need to remove it.

Second, if you pass array into the [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method, it will try to add the whole array as a single item, and hence it will fail. If you want to add all items of one array into another array, you can use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) so that all elements of the array are passed as separate arguments of the push method, e.g

```
const roles = data.roles.map(role => {return {name: role.name}});
this.user.roles.push(...roles);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @TotallyNewb's answer, the problem is with this:
`.map(role => role.name)`

And keep in mind also that map **returns a new array** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Another approach might be to iterate on the response with a forEach and then push:

`data.roles.forEach(role => { this.user.roles.push({name: role.name}) })`